# How can I temporarily fix rotted soffit, fascia, and vented panels?

Tags: roofing

There are very large openings in my soffit/fascia/vented panels that allow water, bird and insects in.  I don't have any woodworking skills, and I'm old and financially not able to repair it properly at this time. How can I temporarily fix the problem?

Would you suggest a roof tarp to cover all and over the sides, stapled, until my situation changes, at least for now?

Comment: How long is "temporary"? A week? A year? This is the kind of problem that can go from minor inconvenience to house-destroying if not fixed. Personal finance advice is not really on-topic here but I think you should be realistic with yourself about when and how this is going to get resolved. Maybe you should look into a home equity loan.

Answer (score 1):

If there's really *no* possible way to fix it then yes, a tarp which is properly added willhelp protect from any further water damage. Simply stapling it isn't sufficient for more than a day or two: winds will either pull the staples loose or tear the tarp, or both. The best way would be to get a tarp which is much larger than you need and some 2x4s. In the places where you are affixing the tarp to the structure, wrap the end of the tarp around the 2x4 a couple of times, and then nail or screw through the 2x4 into the structure. Make sure you get into some solid wood (a joist or stud) instead of just the sheathing.

In your situation (older, not financially or otherwise able to fix it properly) I would reach out to family and friends, and/or check with local government. Someone should be willing to help you out, or maybe there is a local non-profit who can help.